# Question about multivariable polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is probably a very basic question, but I think my ego can take the hit. For a one variable polynomial $p(x)$ it is entirely straightforward that

$p(y)-p(x)=q(y,x)(y-x)$

where $q$ is a polynomial in $y$ and $x$. (Implying in particular that $p$ is Lipschitz on compact sets.)

Does this generalize to polynomials of more than one variable? That is, assume we have $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ a polynomial. Is it true that

$p(y_1,...,y_n)-p(x_1,...,x_n)=q(y_1,...,y_n,x_1,...,x_n)|y-x|$ for some polynomial $q$?

This seems doomed since the norm involves a square root, so I would settle for $(p(y_1,...,y_n)-p(x_1,...,x_n))^2=\tilde{q}(y_1,...,y_n,x_1,...,x_n)|y-x|^2$ where $\tilde{q}$ is a polynomial. I messed around for a few minutes but didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: I would try a simple example like $p(a,b)=ab$ to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For any differentiable function $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ one has the identity

$$f(y)-f(x)=\int_0^1 f'((1-t)x+ty)\,dt\cdot (y-x)$$

If $f$ is a polynomial, or consists of polynomial components, then the integral over the jacobian

$$q(x,y)=\int_0^1 f'((1-t)x+ty)\,dt$$

will also consist of polynomial components.